# Bootstrapping a fitted distribution

Tags: r, distributions, bootstrap, fitting

The following code fits a normal distribution to vector V1 of length 56, and then boostraps and plots the bootstrapped values of parameters. I would like to be certain my understanding of this is correct. Would greatly appreciate any input on the matter.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
V1 <- c(0.18, 0.2, 0.24, 0.35, -0.22, -0.17, 0.28, -0.28, -0.14, 0.03, 0.87, -0.2, 
        0.06, -0.1, -0.72, 0.18, 0.01, 0.31, -0.36, 0.61, -0.16, -0.07, -0.13, 0.01, 
        -0.09, 0.26, -0.14, 0.08, -0.62, -0.2, 0.3, -0.21, -0.11, 0.05, 0.06, -0.28, 
        -0.27, 0.17, 0.42, -0.05, -0.15, 0.05, -0.07, -0.22, -0.34, 0.16, 0.34, 0.1, 
        -0.12, 0.24, 0.45, 0.37, 0.61, 0.9, -0.25, 0.02)
f1 <- fitdist(V1,"norm")    
plotdist(V1,"norm",para=list(mean=f1$estimate[1],sd=f1$estimate[2]))
bnor <- bootdist(f1, niter = 1001)
summary(bnor)
plot(bnor)

#Output for that:
Parametric bootstrap medians and 95% percentile CI 
         Median         2.5%      97.5%
mean 0.03617340 -0.042148291 0.11659871
sd   0.30692538  0.253201396 0.36447153
```

[image]

[image]

My understanding is as follows:

1. Takes V1, and creates a new vector based on V1 that is normally distributed, lets call it VF.
2. Boostraps VF 1001 times. That means using VF to create 1001 vectors, lets call those VFi where i=1001, each of same size as VF (56). That is done by replacement, which means each vector i is made by taking a random element from one of the 56 elements in VF, putting that element in VFi, and then placing that element back into VF before picking again another 55 times ... and then repeating that process 1001 times.
3. That process allows to get a distribution of the statistics of VF, i.e. to get a distribution of VFi's mean and other summary statistics. In this case the code outputs the Median of VFi's mean using the 1001 VFi means. And the final plot, "Boostrapped values of parameters", is plotting those 1001 means.

Is my interpretation accurate?

(By the way, the package's documentation is [here (pdf)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/paper2JSS.pdf).)

Comment: It looks correct.